# Open Hardware Monitor - Voltage Bug?

Tags: c#, openhardwaremonitor

Im using Open Hardware Monitor 0.9.5 for getting some information about my hardware like cpu temp, speed, gpu temp, speed, ram but now i need to upgrade and getting also the Voltage.

So im using this code from 2 years without problem:

```
myComputer = new Computer();
        myComputer.Open();
        myComputer.CPUEnabled = true;
        myComputer.GPUEnabled = true;
        myComputer.MainboardEnabled = true;
        myComputer.RAMEnabled = true;
        myComputer.FanControllerEnabled = true;
        myComputer.HDDEnabled = true;
        

        foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
        {
            hardwareItem.Update();                
            hardwareItem.GetReport();

            //var series = new LineSeries();

            foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
            {                   

                if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Clock)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(sensor.Value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

[image]

Ok so for voltage i just change the SensorType to Voltage:

```
if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Voltage)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(sensor.Value.ToString());
                    }
```

But in this case no message, no data and no voltage, so i think i miss some code, or it is a bug?

Comment: Did you debug the code? Is there in fact any item in the `hardwareItem.Sensors` collection with a `SensorType` value of `SensorType.Voltage`?

Comment: yes, no error no data no value are reported if use SensorType.Voltage

Comment: Sounds like you need to talk to the maintainers of the library and confirm that a) it supports voltage reporting, and b) that your motherboard supports voltage reporting. I don't see what Stack Overflow is going to be able to do about it.

Comment: Yes if i use the open hardware monitor exe i see all voltage, but i will try in another pc and in case i will report this bug